# Declare Variable outside function

Tags: matlab

I am not sure why i can't do this.  Why cant I declare a variable outside a function before it gets used.   I get error an error saying temp is an undefined function or variable.  I realize I can pass the variable into the function thisblah(temp) but that is not what I want to do. The below is a shortened/redacted version of what I want to do.  I am trying to add functionality in an existing function and want to know how many times I enter.  Also I know you can solve calling the temp variable persistent inside the function but I dont think that is right answer. Global doesnt work either.

```
temp = 0;

for i = 1:5
           thisblah
end


function thisblah
  temp = temp + 1;
  if temp(3)
    fprintf('yes a three');
  end
  fprintf('temp is %d, temp);
end
```

Comment: Functions have their own variable scope, please read this: https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2008/01/16/nested-functions-and-variable-scope/ You are best off adding an input *and output* to your function to properly control this. An alternative would be to make `temp` either `persistent` or `global` (which should work, you've given no details why it doesn't for you), but I think you should understand the basics around scoping first

Comment: "_but that is not what I want to do_" In most cases that is what you want to do, so if your case is so special that it requires another aproach you should explain why (what in your problem is excluding the simplest/more robust approach).

Comment: The reason I had trouble with this concept is because of it's use within an .m file.  At least the way I use .m files it seems variables should be held in that .m file scope. For example with .m file use there is no need for a "main" function (I think?) so when I call functions they float within the m file.  Accepting answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Global Approach:

As the comments above have suggested an example of a global approach (making `temp` a global variable) is below. Also, `temp` will not have an 3rd index, `temp(3)` by simply incrementing it. To check when the function has been entered 3 times you can check `if temp == 3`.

```
global temp;
temp = 0;

for i = 1: 5
    thisblah
end

function thisblah

global temp;
  temp = temp + 1;
  if temp == 3
    fprintf('yes a three\n');
  end
  fprintf('temp is %d\n', temp);

end
```

---

### Persistent Approach:

If you make the function in a separate `.m` file you can simply call `clear thisblah` instead of `clear functions` which needs to be there to clear the persistent variable after the script is done being run or before the script is re-run.

```
clc;
for i = 1: 5
    thisblah
end

clear functions;

function thisblah
persistent temp

if isempty(temp)
        temp = 0;
end

temp = temp + 1;
  
  if temp == 3
    fprintf('yes a three\n');
  end
  fprintf('temp is %d\n', temp);

end
```

---

Also, the syntax of line needs changing from:

```
fprintf('temp is %d, temp);
```

to

```
fprintf('temp is %d\n', temp);
```

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**